# Visual Studio 2022 missing options from Build Action property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

While working on a c# winforms app today in VS2022 I noticed I no longer have any items in the dropdowns for Build Action and Copy to Output Directory.

[image]

[image]

I've tried rebooting my computer and just Visual Studio and no luck. These worked before.

Comment: Does it work on a new project?

Comment: Please try to open the Visual Studio Installer, find the version of Visual Studio you are using and click Repair. If this doesn't work, what did you do before this issue appeared?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I ran the repair in VS Installer. After it finished, my options returned. The "repair" also installed an available update as well. I can't say for sure which actually fixed the issue. The update was from 17.2 to 17.4.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This worked for me. My coworker was having the same issue and it did not work for him.

Comment: Not sure why VS Installer updated to 17.4 instead of the latest 17.8. Maybe try updating to that? If still doesn't work, do [report the problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) to Microsoft.

Comment: @MSB I'm glad my suggestion worked for you. You can mark this answer so that it can help more people.

Comment: I have 17.9.0 version and encountered the same problem